# recvmmsg() with timeout = 0 is equivalent to nonblocking recvmsg()?

Tags: c, sockets, linux-kernel, glibc, centos6.5

I am on CentOS 6.5 with kernel version kernel-2.6.32-431.el6.

I was trying to find the implementation of recvmmsg(), and hopefully, I am not looking at the wrong source ~/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-2.6.32-431.el6/linux-2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64/net/socket.c.  If I am, please kindly point me to the right source.

```
int __sys_recvmmsg(int fd, struct mmsghdr __user *mmsg, unsigned int vlen,
                   unsigned int flags, struct timespec *timeout)
{
        int fput_needed, err, datagrams;
        struct socket *sock;
        struct mmsghdr __user *entry;
        struct compat_mmsghdr __user *compat_entry;
        struct msghdr msg_sys;
        struct timespec end_time;

        if (timeout &&
            poll_select_set_timeout(&end_time, timeout->tv_sec,
                                    timeout->tv_nsec))
                return -EINVAL;

        datagrams = 0;

        sock = sockfd_lookup_light(fd, &err, &fput_needed);
        if (!sock)
                return err;

        err = sock_error(sock->sk);
        if (err)
                goto out_put;

        entry = mmsg;
        compat_entry = (struct compat_mmsghdr __user *)mmsg;

        while (datagrams < vlen) {
                /*
                 * No need to ask LSM for more than the first datagram.
                 */
                if (MSG_CMSG_COMPAT & flags) {
                        err = __sys_recvmsg(sock, (struct msghdr __user *)compat_entry,
                                            &msg_sys, flags, datagrams);
                        if (err < 0)
                                break;
                        err = __put_user(err, &compat_entry->msg_len);
                        ++compat_entry;
                } else {
                        err = __sys_recvmsg(sock, (struct msghdr __user *)entry,
                                            &msg_sys, flags, datagrams);
                        if (err < 0)
                                break;
                        err = put_user(err, &entry->msg_len);
                        ++entry;
                }

                if (err)
                        break;
                ++datagrams;

                if (timeout) {
                        ktime_get_ts(timeout);
                        *timeout = timespec_sub(end_time, *timeout);
                        if (timeout->tv_sec < 0) {
                                timeout->tv_sec = timeout->tv_nsec = 0;
                                break;
                        }

                        /* Timeout, return less than vlen datagrams */
                        if (timeout->tv_nsec == 0 && timeout->tv_sec == 0)
                                break;
                }

                /* Out of band data, return right away */
                if (msg_sys.msg_flags & MSG_OOB)
                        break;
        }

out_put:
        fput_light(sock->file, fput_needed);

        if (err == 0)
                return datagrams;

        if (datagrams != 0) {
                /*
                 * We may return less entries than requested (vlen) if the
                 * sock is non block and there aren't enough datagrams...
                 */
                if (err != -EAGAIN) {
                        /*
                         * ... or  if recvmsg returns an error after we
                         * received some datagrams, where we record the
                         * error to return on the next call or if the
                         * app asks about it using getsockopt(SO_ERROR).
                         */
                        sock->sk->sk_err = -err;
                }

                return datagrams;
        }

        return err;
}
```

Let's say there are 2 packets at the socket, and I try:

```
timespec t = {0, 0};
recvmmsg(fd, mmsg, vlen, 0, &t);
```

Then, because of these lines:

```
                    if (timeout->tv_nsec == 0 && timeout->tv_sec == 0)
                            break;
```

recvmmsg() will just return 1 packet instead of 2.  Am I right?

It seems defecting the one of the main purposes of recvmmsg() -- trying to reduce # of system calls when there are packet queued.

Maybe I miss something?

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks!

============================

Update:

I tried to write a small snippet of code that waits for the packets to queue up and then call recvmmsg() with timeout=0 (not NULL).  It still picks up only 1 packet.  Hence, I *think* I am looking at the correct source code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. I think it is better to use NULL timeout + O_NONBLOCK if you want to read all packets in the queue

Answer (score 0):

No. A zero timeout means infinity.

Comment: Quote from recvmmsg manpage: "If timeout is NULL, then the operation blocks indefinitely."  So my code in my original code won't make recvmmsg block indefinitely.

Comment: That's a null timeout parameter. Your question is about a zero timeout, as is my answer.

Comment: Both the manpage and the kernel source code don't indicate that a zero timeout will make recvmmsg() to block indefinitely.  Could you kindly point me to where indicates so?

Comment: Man recvmmsg:
The  timeout  argument points to a struct timespec (see clock_gettime(2)) defining a timeout (seconds plus nanoseconds) for the receive operation (but see BUGS!).  (This interval will be rounded up to  the  system  clock  granularity,  and  kernel scheduling  delays  mean that the blocking interval may overrun by a small amount.)  If timeout is NULL, then the operation blocks indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the recvmmsg timeout parameter and use SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO if necessary. Works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive up to vlen messages exist in receive buffer without blocking, this will solve your problem:

```
recvmmsg(fd, mmsg, vlen, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL);
```

It will loop until the internal recvmsg call returns by an error code like EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK or until vlen count of messages filled in your buffer without blocking.